# Compare distance() with field value in document

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search, google-search-api

I am using google app engine with java and the google search api. I save documents with a geopoint and a maximum distance.

```
Document.Builder builder = Document.newBuilder()
     .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("location").setGeoPoint(new GeoPoint(lat, lon)))
     .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("radius").setNumber(radiusInMeter));
```

Now I want to query for all documents where the set radius is within the distance to a given geopoint like following:

```
String queryString = "radius > distance(location, geopoint(" + lat + ", " + lon + "))";
Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build(queryString);
```

However, if I do this I'll get following exception:

SearchException: Unable to compare "radius" with "distance()"

So my question is, how can I achieve my use-case with google search api?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings) (with my emphasis):

> `distance(point1, point2)`
>
> Computes the distance in meters between two geopoints. Each point can
>   be specified by using the name of a geopoint field or an invocation of
>   the geopoint function. Note that you **cannot provide two field names as
>   arguments** to this function. At least one argument must be a constant.

I don't know your use case but perhaps you can determine the `radius` prior to performing the search, so you can specify it as a constant in your query string?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 
I tried a different query like following: "radius = 500 AND 500 > distance(location, geopoint(" + lat + ", " + lon + "))" but that does not seem to work either (SearchException: Temporary search service error). The API seems to be very restrictive with geopoint calculations.

Comment: I assume `500 > distance(location, geopoint(lat,lon))` does work?

Comment: Yes, that does work but does not give the flexibility to have variable radii. I have to use hard-coded radii now and loop over each set to remove the ones which are in the smaller set of radii. Not very performant with a big dataset.